# how to convert an existing asp.net mvc 3 web application to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a solution with 1 asp.net mvc application and some class libraries (core, repo, service, tests).

What are steps needed to convert this solution to azure ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ASP.NET MVC 3 application is nothing more than an ASP.NET application so the [following blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/02/08/migrating-an-existing-asp-net-app-to-run-on-windows-azure.aspx) stands true.